# Getting child from a namespaced node in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I need to get each child node of the c:batch node. <xsl:template match="s-20"> does not match the node. What did I do wrong? Any help appreciated. Thanx alot in advance.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<c:batch xmlns:a="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive"
         xmlns:i="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive/import"
         xmlns="http://www.test.com/dos/asap"
         xmlns:n1="http://www.test.com/dos"
         xmlns:c="http://www.test.com/data/6/capture">
   <s-20 file="00000001.pdf" checked="true">
      <code>X12345</code>
      <type>data</type>
   </s-20>
   <s-20 file="00000002.pdf" checked="false">
      <code>X67890</code>
      <type>data</type>
   </s-20>
   <s-20 file="00000003.pdf" checked="true">
      <code>X87687</code>
      <type>data</type>
   </s-20>
</c:batch>
```

Stylesheet:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:a="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive"
         xmlns:i="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive/import"
         xmlns="http://www.test.com/dos/asap"
         xmlns:n1="http://www.test.com/dos"
         xmlns:c="http://www.test.com/data/6/capture">
         
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="Documents">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(s-20)"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="s-20">
    <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<s-20>` are in the namespace:

```
xmlns="http://www.test.com/dos/asap"
```

To match them use an explicit namespace in the XSLT, e.g. add the line

```
xmlns:t="http://www.test.com/dos/asap"
```

to your `<xsl:stylesheet>` root element in your XSLT and prefix your matching rules with `t:`. Also use `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of` in your `s-20` template. Then all `s-20` elements would be copied to the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:a="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive"
         xmlns:i="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive/import"
         xmlns:t="http://www.test.com/dos/asap"
         xmlns:n1="http://www.test.com/dos"
         xmlns:c="http://www.test.com/data/6/capture">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/c:batch">
    <xsl:element name="Documents">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(t:s-20)"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="t:s-20">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Documents>3
  <s-20 xmlns:a="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive" xmlns:i="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive/import" xmlns="http://www.test.com/dos/asap" xmlns:n1="http://www.test.com/dos" xmlns:c="http://www.test.com/data/6/capture" file="00000001.pdf" checked="true">
        <code>X12345</code>
        <type>data</type>
    </s-20>
    <s-20 xmlns:a="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive" xmlns:i="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive/import" xmlns="http://www.test.com/dos/asap" xmlns:n1="http://www.test.com/dos" xmlns:c="http://www.test.com/data/6/capture" file="00000002.pdf" checked="false">
        <code>X67890</code>
        <type>data</type>
    </s-20>
    <s-20 xmlns:a="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive" xmlns:i="http://www.test.com/data/6/archive/import" xmlns="http://www.test.com/dos/asap" xmlns:n1="http://www.test.com/dos" xmlns:c="http://www.test.com/data/6/capture" file="00000003.pdf" checked="true">
        <code>X87687</code>
        <type>data</type>
    </s-20>
</Documents>
```